# Ruby on Rails - Nested Attributes Creating Duplicate Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Please don't flag this as duplicate. I've already reviewed the other similar questions and mine is different.

I have an issue where some of the users that input their addresses manage to create duplicate CartAddress records.

My database structure includes a Cart model and CartAddress model.

The Cart model looks something like this:

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :cart_addresses, -> { order(address_type: :asc) }, inverse_of: :cart, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :cart_addresses, allow_destroy: true 

end
```

My CartAddress model looks like this:

```
class CartAddress < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :cart

    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true

    validates :email, presence: true
    validates :telephone, presence: true
    validates :address_line_one, presence: true
    validates :city, presence: true
    validates :country, presence: true
    validates :state, presence: true
    validates :zip_code, presence: true

    validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i


end
```

When the user loads the cart page:

```
def index
    #bunch of init code here
    #more here

    @exists = true
    if @cart.cart_addresses.count == 0
        @exists = false
        2.times { @cart.cart_addresses.build(country: "United States", state: "Alabama")}
   end
end
```

Then when I create/update:

```
def update_addresses
    @countries = Country.all
    @states = State.all 
    @cart = Cart.find(params[:cart][:id])   
    if params[:cart][:cart_addresses_attributes]["0"][:address_type] == "Billing" and params[:cart][:cart_addresses_attributes]["1"][:address_type] == "Shipping"

        @cart.update(params.require(:cart).permit(cart_addresses_attributes: [:id, :address_type, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :telephone, :address_line_one, :address_line_two, :city, :zip_code, :country, :state]))


    #bunch of other code 

 end
```

Here is my partial that renders the form

```
    <%= form_for(cart, :remote => true, :url => update_cart_addresses_path, :html => {:class => 'addresses-class', :id => 'cart-addresses', :autocomplete => :off}) do |u| %>
        <% billing = true %>
        <% state = 0 %>
        <%= u.hidden_field :id %>
        <% offset_two = true %>

        <% if @exists == true %>
            <%= u.fields_for :cart_addresses do |b| %>

                    <%= b.hidden_field :address_type %>

                    <% if billing == true %>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <h4>Billing Address</h4>
                            <% billing = false %>
                        </div>
                    <% else %>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 pad-top-15 checkout-section-padding">
                            <h4>Shipping Address</h4>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="same-as-billing" name="same_as_billing" value="1" onclick="toggleShippingAddress(this);">Same as Billing?
                        </div>
                    <% end %>

                <div class="address">

                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <%= b.label :first_name %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                        <%= b.text_field :first_name, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field required', :data => {:hj_whitelist => ''}%>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <%= b.label :last_name %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                        <%= b.text_field :last_name, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field required', :data => {:hj_whitelist => ''} %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 pad-top-15">
                        <%= b.label :email %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                        <%= b.email_field :email, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field required', :data => {:hj_whitelist => ''} %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 pad-top-15">
                        <%= b.label :telephone %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                        <%= b.text_field :telephone, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field required', :data => {:hj_whitelist => ''} %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 pad-top-15">
                        <%= b.label :address_line_one %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                        <%= b.text_field :address_line_one, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field required', :data => {:hj_whitelist => ''} %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 pad-top-15">

                        <%= b.text_field :address_line_two, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field', :data => {:hj_whitelist => ''} %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 pad-top-15">
                        <%= b.label :city %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                        <%= b.text_field :city, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field required', :data => {:hj_whitelist => ''} %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 pad-top-15">
                        <%= b.label :country %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                        <%= b.select(:country, countries.all.collect {|a| [a.name]}, {:prompt => "Select A Country"}, :onchange => "setStates(#{state});", class: 'checkout-country') %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 pad-top-15">
                        <div id="<%= "state_" + state.to_s %>">
                            <%= b.label :state %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                            <%= b.text_field :state, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field' %>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 pad-top-15">
                        <%= b.label :zip_code%><span class="required-field">*</span>
                        <%= b.text_field :zip_code, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field required', :data => {:hj_whitelist => ''} %>
                    </div>



                    <% state = state + 1 %>               

                </div>          
            <% end %>
        <% else %>
            <%= u.fields_for :cart_addresses do |b| %>

                    <% if billing == true %>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <h4>Billing Address</h4>
                            <% billing = false %>
                            <%= b.hidden_field :address_type, value: "Billing" %>
                        </div>
                    <% else %>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 pad-top-15 checkout-section-padding">
                            <h4>Shipping Address</h4>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="same-as-billing" name="same_as_billing" value="1" onclick="toggleShippingAddress(this);">Same as Billing?
                            <%= b.hidden_field :address_type, value: "Shipping" %>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
                <div class="address">                       


                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <%= b.label :first_name %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                        <%= b.text_field :first_name, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field required', :data => {:hj_whitelist => ''} %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <%= b.label :last_name %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                        <%= b.text_field :last_name, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field required', :data => {:hj_whitelist => ''} %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 pad-top-15">
                        <%= b.label :email %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                        <%= b.email_field :email, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field required', :data => {:hj_whitelist => ''} %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 pad-top-15">
                        <%= b.label :telephone %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                        <%= b.text_field :telephone, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field required', :data => {:hj_whitelist => ''} %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 pad-top-15">
                        <%= b.label :address_line_one %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                        <%= b.text_field :address_line_one, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field required', :data => {:hj_whitelist => ''} %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 pad-top-15">

                        <%= b.text_field :address_line_two, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field', :data => {:hj_whitelist => ''} %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 pad-top-15">
                        <%= b.label :city %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                        <%= b.text_field :city, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field required', :data => {:hj_whitelist => ''} %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 pad-top-15">
                        <%= b.label :country %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                        <%= b.select(:country, countries.all.collect {|a| [a.name]}, {:prompt => "Select A Country"}, :onchange => "setStates(#{state});", class: 'checkout-country') %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 pad-top-15">
                        <div id="<%= "state_" + state.to_s %>">
                            <%= b.label :state %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                            <%= b.text_field :state, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field' %>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 pad-top-15">
                        <%= b.label :zip_code %><span class="required-field">*</span>
                        <%= b.text_field :zip_code, class: 'checkout-addr-text-field required', :data => {:hj_whitelist => ''} %>
                    </div>



                    <% state = state + 1 %> 
                </div>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

<div class="col-xs-12 pad-top-15">
    <button id="update-checkout-addresses-btn" class="checkout-addresses-submit-btn btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="submitCheckoutAddressesForm(this);" type="button">Update Addresses</button>
</div>
```

When creating new address records the form is submitted without an id. When editing the records a id is submitted. Somehow it appears that the form is being submitted more than once although I do have javascript disabling the form upon submission. How should I handle this in the controller to prevent this error from happening? Or fix my view partial?

UPDATE

Here is my JS

```
function submitCheckoutAddressesForm(element){
    element.disabled = true;
    var e = document.getElementById("same-as-billing")
    sameAsBillingCheckout(e);
    $(e).closest("form").submit();
}
```

The below function makes sure that all the elements are the same in the form if a checkbox "Shipping Address Same As Billing" is selected. The reason I am having to clone the element and copy it into the shipping addresses is because the element type has the ability to change due to other javascript. I figured this would be the safest way of handling this event just to ensure that the proper elements were submitted in the form. I don't see that this should effect the duplicate records being created.

```
function sameAsBillingCheckout(element){
    if(element.checked == true){
    var billing = ["#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_first_name", "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_last_name", "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_email", "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_telephone", 
    "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_address_line_one", "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_address_line_two", "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_country", "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_state", "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_city", "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_zip_code"]


    var shipping = ["#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_1_first_name", "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_1_last_name", "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_1_email", "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_1_telephone", 
    "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_1_address_line_one", "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_1_address_line_two", "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_1_country", "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_1_state", "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_1_city", "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_1_zip_code"]

    for(i = 0; i < billing.length; i++){
        $(shipping[i]).val($(billing[i]).val()); 

        if(billing[i] == "#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_country"){
            $("#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_1_state").remove();

            var e = document.getElementById("cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_state");

            var cln = e.cloneNode(true);
            cln.name = "cart[cart_addresses_attributes][1][state]";
            cln.id = "cart_cart_addresses_attributes_1_state";

            var stateDiv = document.getElementById("state_1");
            stateDiv.appendChild(cln);  
        }
    }

   }
}
```

This code below does the same as the javascript above. It's just submitting the form after the user finishes typing if the form isn't disabled.

```
$(function(){
   //create one instance for handler:
   var myHandler = function(e){

        var sAB = document.getElementById("same-as-billing").checked;
        var ready = true;
        //LOOPS THROUGH ALL THE TEXT FIELDS
        $('.checkout-addr-text-field').each(function (){
        //IF SAME AS BILLING CHECKBOX SELECTED
        if(sAB == true){
            //if the field is disabled or the field includes _0_ (means its a billing address field) and the id is not the optional field and the value isn't blank then dont submit the form. 
            if(this.disabled || this.id.indexOf("_0_") !== -1 && this.id != 
    "cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_address_line_two" && this.value == ""){
                ready = false;
            }
        }else{ // IF SAME AS BILLING CHECKBOX NOT SELECTED
            if(this.disabled || this.id != 
    "cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_address_line_two" && this.id != 
    "cart_cart_addresses_attributes_1_address_line_two" && this.value == ""){
                ready = false;
            }
        }
    });

   if(ready == true){


        var e = document.getElementById("same-as-billing")
        sameAsBillingCheckout(e);
        $(e).closest("form").submit();
        $("#cart-addresses :input").attr("disabled", true);

   }
   };



$(document).on('keyup', '.checkout-addr-text-field', debounce(function(e){
        myHandler(e);
    }, 1700));


$(document).on('change', '#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_state', function(e){
            myHandler(e);
    });

$(document).on('change', '#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_1_state', function(e){

            myHandler(e);

    });

$(document).on('change', '#cart_cart_addresses_attributes_0_state', function(e){

            myHandler(e);

    });

$(document).on('click', '#same-as-billing', function(e){
        if(this.checked){
            myHandler(e);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: can you share this `submitCheckoutAddressesForm()` function here?

Comment: @AneesMuhammed I've added in the JS to the original question.

Comment: Can you paste some logs on params when a user submit multiple addresses ?

Comment: So is not the form submitted twice because 1) user presses button, and 2) timeout auto-submits the form. Or user changes a state, the form is ready and is submitted and _then_ the timer expires? Why auto-submit on creation? (that is hard because indeed there is no id --on edit it makes not difference how many times you save/update the same data).